# Adding swipe support to sudoslider, swiping doesn't work

Tags: jquery-mobile, slider, swipe

I've tried adding swipe-support to [SudoSlider](http://webbies.dk/SudoSlider/) via [Jquery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/), but so far it doesn't seem to work. Both on the ipad and the iphone nothing happens when tried swiping.

Minimal working example of my page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery.sudoSlider.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery.mobile.custom.min.js"></script>
  </head>
    <body>
      <div id="container">
            <div id="pages">
                <ul class="pages">
                    <li class="page" id="front"></li>
                    <li class="page" id ="about"></li>
                    <li class="page" id ="who"></li>
                    <li class="page" id="services"></li>
                    <li class="page" id="projects"></li>
                    <li class="page" id="contact"></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
      </div>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
    var sudoSlider = $("#pages").sudoSlider({
        history:           true,
        prevNext:          false,
        continuous:        true,
        customLink:        'a.slide-controller',
        numericText:['home', 'mission', 'about', 'services', 'portfolio', 'contact']
        });

        $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        switch(e.keyCode) {
          case 37 : sudoSlider.goToSlide("prev"); break;
          case 39 : sudoSlider.goToSlide("next"); break;
        }

        $("#pages").swiperight(function() {
            sudoSlider.goToSlide("next");
        });

        $("#pages").swipeleft(function() {
            sudoSlider.goToSlide("prev");
        });
      });
    });
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I am not an jquery mobile expert, I think you need to bind the swipe events to the pages, like `$("#pages").bind("swipeleft", function() {...});`

Also you should take a look at the documentation to use `$(document).bind('pageinit')` instead of  `$(document).ready()`

Visit http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html and take a look at the first yellow box; the swipe events are also explained there below.

Comment: Thanks for that. I also noted that I placed my bindings within the keyup event (...)